# Change the path for the flexslider slides

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the path that the [flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) uses for its slides.  The upload area for the new slides is in one place and the directory that the flexslider displays the slides from is in another.

Comment: Please give more details about this: what are the paths now, how would you like the paths to be, how are you using flexslider (fields, views, other)

Comment: Currently, when an image is uploaded, it is uploaded to /files/basicpage.  The flexslider looks for slides in /files/styles/top_slider/public/basicpage.  I am trying to figure out how to change the path that the flexslider uses to the default upload one.